# Nested for-loop overwrites object attribute

Tags: javascript

I broke down my code to a simplified jsFiddle. The problem is that the attribute `is` is only set for one object but in the end every object gets the value of the last iteration (in this case it is `false` but `id05` should be `true`). Why is it? Do I overlook something?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fnxz1oo/) (see in the console)

```
var reminder = {
    id0: {
        id: 0,
        medId: 0
    }
};

var chart = {
    id0: {
        medId: 0,
        values: [[5,1]]
    }
}
var tmp = {};

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (id in reminder) {
        tmp[id + i] = reminder[id];
        tmp[id + i].is = false;

        for(var j = 0; j < chart["id" + reminder[id].medId].values.length; j++) {
            if (chart["id" + reminder[id].medId].values[j][0] === i) {
                tmp[id + i].is = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tmp[id + i] = reminder[id];` will copy the reference to the object and not clone the object itself.

Consider this:

```
var a = { a: [] }; 
var b = a.a; 
b.push(1);
console.log(a.a); // [1]
```

This means that all your objects are the same and they share the same properties (`tmp.id05 === tmp.id06` etc...)

```
tmp.id00.__my_secret_value__ = 1234;
console.log(tmp.id09.__my_secret_value__); // 1234
```

To clone objects in JavaScript you can use `Object.create` but this will only make a shallow clone (only clone top level properties)

Comment: I was scratching my head for a while. Nice!

Comment: Alright, thanks. So I even changed the original object?!

Comment: @BMS Yes, you only operate on one object because you copy the reference to it.